# SharePoint Online - Custom User properties not found in Refinement

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-userprofile

I'm developping against SharePoint Online. Added 2 custom user properties **Agency** and **Company** and populated them for all my users by getting data from the active directory through PowerShell.

I've also created 2 managed properties which are mapping respectivelly the custom properties.

Now i'm trying to create a PeopleResults page but it seems that I can't find these properties in the refinement webpart.

What should I do? What I'm missing? I've been pulling my hair for two days now ...

**EDIT:**

SPO apparently does not detect new managed properties in the refinement webpart. I used  pre-defined Refinable properties: `RefinableString00` and `RefinableString01`. Waited a while so that all user profiles get indexed and now and I see filter them with these pre-defined props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to create new Refinable Managed Properties in SharePoint online. You need to use one of the pre-defined Refinable properties, for example: RefinableString00, RefinableString01, etc. This is a nice explanation: http://spr.com/overcoming-office-365sharepoint-online-development-challenges-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the Default Privacy Setting is set to Everyone for the user properties to be displayed in the refinement webpart?
The setting needs to be set to Everyone since the search components need to be able to access it.

Comment: It is diplayed to everyone.